# How to override composer repository source?

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I'm trying to fork a repo so I can update it with my own code. I've done it before, but something seems to be missing this time.
When I put the repo path in the composer repository list, it will usually detect that it matches the package and use the package from my repo.
Here's my composer (simplified for example sake):

```
{
    "name": "My Project",
    "description": "Project",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "repositories" : [
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/phazei/laravel4-datatables-package.git",
            "type": "git"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/phazei/cashier.git",
            "type": "git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "bllim/datatables": "dev-master-phazei",
        "laravel/cashier": "dev-test"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Both requirements are being overridden the exact same way as far as I can tell.  The bllim/datatables reads the "master-phazei" branch from the overridden repository, but cashier seems to entirely ignore it.

If I type `composer show bllim/datatables` it will list my repo for the source.  But if I type `composer show laravel/cashier` it shows as if I didn't even have my repo listed.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I went and read https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository again.

I noticed it said the package name needed to match or it wouldn't work.  I had cloned it directly from the main branch, so I had no reason to suspect it not matching, but it seems it was renamed from "laravel/cashier" to "laravel/new-cashier".  That doesn't match the packagist name so it didn't know it was the one.  Packagist doesn't look at any updated package names.  So I had to revert my fork to the old name and it worked.